# FormGroup validation TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Im learning angular 10, but I have a trouble

I have a html document that validate a formgoup in my component.
When from my component set a value of textbox the value is displayed ok, but my submit button says that is invalid (required).

Let me show....

Component

```
 export class PersonalComponent implements OnInit {

  personalForm = new FormGroup({

      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")])
    });
 public name: string = '';
 public email: string = '';
 public submitted = false;
```

Method

```
  getPersonalData() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(prm => {
        this.service.getPersonal(prm['id']).subscribe(data => {
          this.name = data.name;
          this.email = data.email;
        },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    })
  }
```

Save method

```
onSave(form: Personal) {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.personalSaveForm.valid) {
      this.service.postPersonal(form).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('saved');
      },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
```

Html document

```
<form [formGroup]="personalSaveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave($event)">

 <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="name" value="{{name}}" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': submitted}" formControlName="name" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

 <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="email" value="{{email}}" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': submitted}" formControlName="name" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

      <div class=" col-sm-12 align-items-right">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">Next</button>
      </div>
```

So, as seen, from the component sets value (for default) for textbox, but when the button is pushed still validate!!! even has a value!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some flaws here:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <input type="text" id="email" value="{{email}}" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': submitted}" formControlName="name" class="form-control" required />
</div>
```

The `formControlName` needs to be `email` as the FormGroup value.

Also, if you are using a `Validators.required` there is no need to use `required` in your HTML because the form has a programatic validation that makes it required. Another thing to point out is to avoid the use of `values` directly in the input because it may collide with the formControl value itself.

To set the value of your form control in your component.ts use this syntax.

```
this.personalSaveForm.get('name').setValue('New Name')
```

To match a variable directly into an input, you will probably need to use the template-driven `ngModel` (which I personally dislike).

Finally remember that `''` is falsy in JS, so if you use that value as the default, the form will be `invalid` as default.

Comment: remove the "value" in the input tag, it make me feel ill :)